# Why is ordered pair representation as a set correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Textbook shows ordered pair as the following set. Why so ?

$\left (  a , b\right) = \left \{ \left \{ a \right \},\left \{ a,b \right \} \right \}$

If the RHS is a set it is unordered there RHS can be re-written as $\left \{ \left \{ a,b \right \},\left \{ a \right \} \right \}$ or even $\left \{ \left \{ b,a \right \},\left \{ a \right \} \right \}$

Is $(b,a)$ representation as a set really different from $(a,b)$